# Effects of subliminal messaging

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, experimental-psychology, psychology, consumer-psychology

From what I've read up thus far, subliminal messages do have some sort of 'influence' over our decisions or atleast our thought process, to some extent. To what extent if any is the human mind or psyche affected by subliminal messages, and are the extents variable based on the means ie. Textual, verbal, auditory or visual?

The below links are of sources written by authors without substantial credentials:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-athletes-way/201504/subliminal-messages-can-fortify-inner-strength%3famp

https://visme.co/blog/subliminal-messages/

Comment: This [article](https://skepticalinquirer.org/1996/11/scientific_consensus_and_expert_testimony_lessons_from_the_judas_priest_trial/) has a great overview of one of the more famous cases of subliminal messaging and reveals that there is little evidence subliminal prompts can affect behavior.

Comment: It still seems a controversy, though recent studies favor it having effects. I don’t have a comprehensive review for you, but Section 6. Subliminal Priming & Advertisements in [Elgendi M, et al. Subliminal Priming—State of the Art and Future Perspectives.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6027235/?report=classic) has a brief recent review on advertising effects, and [Ruch S, et al. Subliminal messages exert long-term effects on decision-making.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6204644/?report=classic) is a recent article on long term effects. They may give u some info.

Answer (score 1):

## A very generic question

It is very hard to answer this question because it is very generic.

In order to get a clearer answer you'd have to narrow down your definition of what exactly constitutes *subliminal message* and what exactly constitutes an *effect*.

Once done, you can now talk about specific types of *stimuli processed purely by the subconscious*, and their specific effect and related variables.

Here are some examples of what might constitute 'subliminal messages':

- A metaphor
- Asking someone to hold a warm cup of coffee
- Putting an image of eyes in the room
- 'planting' a video frame in a sequences of other frames

The effect (and the extent) of all of these depends on the 'message' itself and the specifics of the experiment.

You can read further about this 'complexity' simply by reading [Wikipedia's entry on Subliminal Stimuli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli) (and the references therein).

## A very generic answer

Without specifics, you can argue the following:

> There is mounting evidence that pure subconscious processing can affect our behaviour, albeit often short lived.

## Resources

I could point you to many resources dealing with specific cases, but I think you'll find much of what you're after (or at least a good subset/overview) in the first couple of chapters of this book:

*Dehaene, S., 2014. Consciousness and the brain: Deciphering how the brain codes our thoughts. Penguin.*

Comment: Im afraid the question would need to be fairly generic, basic even, my knowledge on this topic is limited. I see your point, would you even refer to subliminal messaging as a sort of pseudo-science? Perhaps similar to hypnotism in a sense, due to  competing theories, and lack of complete evidence?